# Bash Scripting: Require script to be run as root (or with sudo)

Tags: bash, scripting, root, permissions

I'm trying to write a bash script (in Ubuntu) that will backup a directory using tar.

How can I do a check in the script so that it can only be run as root (or with sudo)?

For instance, if a user runs the script, it should say that this script must be run with sudo privileges, and then quit. If the script is executed as root, it will continue past the check.

I know there has to be an easy solution, I just haven't been able to find it by googling.

Comment: Recently, I've seen things like systemd elevate privileges automatically with user password entered. I'd be interested in an answer that can not only alert the user they don't have the needed permissions, but offer to elevate it for them instead of forcing a restart.

Comment: came here looking for something like that. I'm building up a script which has sudo usage in the middle of it... would be nice to get it right from the start, but none of the solutions presented here so far have worked (both `id -u` and `sudo id -u` come out as "1000" instead of 0)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

To pull the effective uid use this command:

```
id -u
```

If the result is ‘0’ then the script is either running as root, or using sudo.  You can run the check by doing something like:

```
if [[ $(/usr/bin/id -u) -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Not running as root"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: I'd recommend fully-qualifying the path to id (e.g., /usr/bin/id).  Otherwise a devious user could write their own script/binary that always returns 0 and then put it in a location that exists earlier in the executing users' path.

Comment: Agreed.  Fixing with an edit.

Comment: Anyone 'devious' trying to run the script won't be stopped by you using the full path to id.

Comment: I agree with theother... it's a bash script. Qualifying the 'id' bin won't stop anyone who is seriously intent on getting around the check anyway. Better to leave it unqualified for portability.

Comment: This doesn't address the "sudo" requirement.

Answer (score 21):

I assume you know that by changing the ownership to root

`chown root:root file`

and setting the permissions to 700

`chmod 700 file`

you will accomplish the same thing - without the suggestion to run as sudo.

But I will post this answer for completeness.

Comment: This is a more appopriate solution than the accepted answer. - My $0.02

Comment: Side note: checking the script into git becomes harder. To fix, `sudo git add <file>`

Answer (score 12):

The bash variable `$EUID` shows the effective UID the script is running at, if you want to make sure the script runs as root, check wether `$EUID` contains the value 0 or not:

```
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "$0 is not running as root. Try using sudo."
    exit 2
fi
```

This is better than the solution with `/usr/bin/id` (for bash scripts!) because it doesn't require an external command.

Comment: Instead of just exiting, could prompt the user for sudo login by replacing the `echo` line with `sudo "$0" "$@"`, and replace `exit 2` with `exit $?`.

Comment: Good idea. However the question asked for a script that quit, not ran sudo by itself.

Comment: Instead of starting a subprocess and forwarding the exit status, just replace the current process with the privileged one using `exec` (e.g., `exec sudo "$0" "$@"`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use whoami command as well.

```
if [ ! "`whoami`" = "root" ]
then
    echo "\nPlease run script as root."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Actually the uid 0 is the special user account with full privilege. "root" is simply the most common label/name mapped to that UID. It doesn't *have* to be 'root' and an attacker may try to exploit this.

Answer (score 2):

What is your objective here, to inform the user that they should run the script as root or as some kind of security precaution?

If you just want to inform the user than any of the uid suggestions are fine, but they're as useful as tyres on a horse as a security precaution - there's nothing to stop a user from copying the script, taking out the if statement, and running it anyway.

If this is a security issue then the script should be set to 700, owned by root:root, so that it is not readable or executable by any other user.

Comment: Or, it could be the script requires access to files or commands only accessible to root in order to carry out its work, as in my case

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to make the script only runnable by root is to start the script with the line:
`#!/bin/su root`

Answer (score -1):

"#!/bin/su root" allows users in super user mode to run the script without using the root password. If you want super users to run the script with results that of root, this does that.